# compression: httpZip vs Anything IIS 7 has to offer

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, compression

I'm trying to evaluate IIS compression tools out there, and saw httpZip.  I was wondering if anyone could make a recommendation, did it help and was it substantial?  Was IIS 7 even on the same level (performance or configuration, or any other category)?

Answer (score 0):

IIS7 made huge improvements with compression abilities for both static and dynamic content.  Here is some info:

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpCompression